# How to change LinuxFxVersion in Azure function app

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions

i have azure function with `LinuxFxVersion` set to `DOTNET`:

```
"siteProperties": {
"metadata": null,
"properties": [
    {
        "name": "LinuxFxVersion",
        "value": "DOTNET|3.1"
    },
    {
        "name": "WindowsFxVersion",
        "value": null
    }
  ],
    "appSettings": null
},
```

I want to set it to `Python`:

```
"siteProperties": {
"metadata": null,
"properties": [
    {
        "name": "LinuxFxVersion",
        "value": "Python|3.9"
    },
    {
        "name": "WindowsFxVersion",
        "value": null
    }
  ],
    "appSettings": null
},
```

According to [msdn source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/set-runtime-version?tabs=azurecli#manual-version-updates-on-linux), I need to use Power shell to change it:

```
az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version 'Python|3.9'
```

but im getting error:

```
'3.9' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

When im typing just `'Python'` i get response:

```
Operation returned an invalid status 'Bad Request'
```

How to change linux fx version in Azure Function from .NET to Python?

Comment: Based on the error, it looks like you're running this in `cmd` rather than from PowerShell. You might have to escape the `|`: `'Python^|3.9'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen same error

Comment: Did you try to escape | character in Powershell with back slash \ like this "Python\|3.9"

Comment: This should work. `az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version '"Python|3.9"'` https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you can solve this error in Powershell is to wrap up the string containing the pipe character with quotes.

Here are multiple examples:

- `az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version '"Python|3.9"'`
- `az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version 'Python"|"3.9'`

If you are running the above command in bash use : instead of |

- `az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version "Python:3.9"`

https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping

https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/7874

Comment: the `az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version '"Python|3.9"'` worked perfectly, thanks

Comment: it doesnt work when i try az functionapp config set --name <func_name> --resource-group <rg> --linux-fx-version '"DOTNET|6.0"' any idea why?